# Rotation in OpenGL has different effect each time

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

I am trying to learn OpenGL by coding some stuff, but am still not able to understand the concept of rotation.

Here is my code:

```cpp
glm::mat4 projection1 = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
glm::mat4 view1 =camera.GetViewMatrix();////    //
ourShader.setMat4("projection", projection1);
ourShader.setMat4("view", view1);
ourShader.setInt ("pass1",1);           
glm::mat4 model1 = glm::mat4(1.0f);
vangle+=0.1;
float cvangle = (vangle-90)*PI /180;
model1=glm::translate (model1 ,glm::vec3(cos(cvangle )*50,0,sin(cvangle )*50));
model1 = glm::scale(model1, glm::vec3(1,1, 1));             
model1 = glm::rotate(model1,3.0f , glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
model1 = glm::rotate(model1,2.0f, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)); 
ourShader.setMat4("model", model1);
ourModel.Draw(ourShader);
```

The helicopter should rotate around the camera, but my problem is that the rotation has a different effect in each angle, i.e. at angle 0, it looks like this:

[image: angle 0]

while at angle 90, it looks like this:

[image: angle 90]

My goal is to rotate the helicopter around the camera showing always the same side.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i think, change this: `(vangle-90)*PI /180;` to this: `(vangle-90.0)*PI /180.0;`. maybe the compiler converted the value to integer which takes round-off.

Comment: Problem seems to be you are rotating the object around an arbitrary point in space rather than around the camera a fixed distance. Have a go at reordering your transformations such that you translate the object to the cameras position, rotate, and translate to an updated position on the circle.

Comment: @jackw11111 maybe you are correct. the problem is in translating, because even when I comment out the rotation function the problem does not go away I still see all faces of the object while orbiting. I want some thing like earth and moon. The moon is orbiting around the earth but we can only see one side of the moon from any position in the earth.

Comment: Thats because the translate call is doing some sort of rotation when you displace the position by the trig values of the angle, but I would recommend using rotate to do the dirty work for you and use translate just to orient its perp distance from the camera. @Rabbid76 has an answer detailing how to rotate like you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rotate an object in place, then you've to dot the rotation before the translation:

```non
model = translate * rotate;
```

If you want to rotate around a point, then you've to translate the object (by the rotation radius) and then rotate the translated object:

```
model = rotate * translate
```

Note, the operations like [`rotate`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#gaee9e865eaa9776370996da2940873fd4), [`scale`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#ga05051adbee603fb3c5095d8cf5cc229b) and [`translate`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#ga1a4ecc4ad82652b8fb14dcb087879284), define a new matrix and multiply the input matrix by the new matrix.

So In your case the `translate` has to be done after a rotation (`rotate`) around the z axis:

```cpp
vangle+=0.1;

glm::mat4 model1 = glm::mat4(1.0f);

model1 = glm::rotate(model1, glm::radians(vangle), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1)); 
model1 = glm::translate(model1, glm::vec3(50.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

model1 = glm::scale(model1, glm::vec3(1, 1, 1));
```

Comment: Thanks guys this fixes the problem. I used trig like drawing in 2D and that was the cause of  the unwanted result. Your solution with the rotation around Y not Z is good for me